# Python 3 Graphical calculator "bool object is not callable" error

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Below is my attempt at a graphical calculator using Python 3. All the number, cancel and equals buttons work as they should. The issue I have is that when the '+' or '-' buttons are pressed, I receive this error message: "TypeError: 'bool' object is not callable." I would greatly appreciate if anyone could shed some light onto what this error message refers to and means.

```
from tkinter import *

class functions():

    def __init__(self):
        self.cumulative = 0
        self.input = 0;
        self.new_value = True
        self.calculation = False
        self.operation = ""
        self.operation = False

    def numpress(self, num):
        self.number_equals = False
        nostring = display_screen.get()
        no2 = str(num)
        if self.new_value:
            self.input = no2
           self.new_value = False
        else:
           self.input = nostring + no2
        self.display(self.input)

    def calc_total(self):
        self.number_equals = True
        self.input = int(self.input)
        if self.calculation == True:
            self.addition_calc()
        else:
            self.total = int(display_screen.get())

    def display(self, value):
        display_screen.delete(0, END)
        display_screen.insert(0, value)

    def addition_calc(self):

        if self.operation == "addition":
            self.total += self.input
        if self.operation == "subtraction":
            self.cumulative -= self.input

        self.new_value = True
        self.calculation = False
        self.display(self.total)

    def operation(self, operation):
        self.input = int(self.input)
        if self.calculation:
            self.calc_total()
        elif not self.number_equals:
            self.total = self.input
        self.new_value = True
        self.calculation = True
        self.operation = operation
        self.number_equals = False

    def cancel(self):
        self.number_equals = False
        self.input = "0"
        self.display(0)
        self.new_value = True
        self.total = 0

ops = functions()
root = Tk()
root.resizable(0,0)
frame = Frame(root)
frame.pack()

root.title("Calculator")

screen_num=StringVar()
bgcolour="#000"
fgcolour="#00FF00"
display_screen=Entry (frame, bd=10, insertwidth=1, font=30)
display_screen.pack( side =TOP)

topframe = Frame(root)
topframe.pack(side = TOP)

b1 = Button(topframe,padx=24, pady=8, bd =6, text = "1", fg="black",)
b1.pack(side = LEFT)
b1["command"] = lambda: ops.numpress(1)

b2 = Button(topframe,padx=24, pady=8, bd =6, text = "2", fg="black",)
b2.pack(side = LEFT)
b2["command"] = lambda: ops.numpress(2)

b3 = Button(topframe,padx=24, pady=8, bd =6, text = "3", fg="black",)
b3.pack(side = LEFT)
b3["command"] = lambda: ops.numpress(3)

frame1 = Frame(root)
frame1.pack(side = TOP)

b4 = Button(frame1,padx=24, pady=8, bd =6, text = "4", fg="black",)
b4.pack(side = LEFT)
b4["command"] = lambda: ops.numpress(4)

b5 = Button(frame1,padx=24, pady=8, bd =6, text = "5", fg="black",)
b5.pack(side = LEFT)
b5["command"] = lambda: ops.numpress(5)

b6 = Button(frame1,padx=24, pady=8, bd =6, text = "6", fg="black",)
b6.pack(side = LEFT)
b6["command"] = lambda: ops.numpress(6)

frame2 = Frame(root)
frame2.pack(side = TOP)

b7 = Button(frame2,padx=24, pady=8, bd =6, text = "7", fg="black")
b7.pack(side = LEFT)
b7["command"] = lambda: ops.numpress(7)

b8 = Button(frame2,padx=24, pady=8, bd =6, text = "8", fg="black")
b8.pack(side = LEFT)
b8["command"] = lambda: ops.numpress(8)

b9 = Button(frame2,padx=24, pady=8, bd =6, text = "9", fg="black")
b9.pack(side = LEFT)
b9["command"] = lambda: ops.numpress(9)

frame3=Frame(root)
frame3.pack(side=TOP)

button0=Button(frame3,padx=24, pady=8, bd=6, text="0", fg="black")
button0.pack(side=LEFT)
button0["command"] = lambda: ops.numpress(0)

command=Frame(root)
command.pack(side=TOP)

buttonPlus=Button(command,padx=24, pady=8, bd =6, text = "+", fg="black")
buttonPlus.pack(side=LEFT)
buttonPlus["command"] = lambda: ops.operation("addition")

buttonMinus=Button(command,padx=24, pady=8, bd =6, text = "-", fg="black")
buttonMinus.pack(side=LEFT)
buttonMinus["command"] = lambda: ops.operation("subtraction")

buttonCancel=Button(command,padx=24, pady=8, bd =6, text = "C", fg="black")
buttonCancel.pack(side=LEFT)
buttonCancel["command"] = ops.cancel

command1=Frame(root)
command1.pack(side=TOP)

buttonEquals=Button(command1,padx=24, pady=8, bd =6, text = "=", fg="black")
buttonEquals.pack(side=LEFT)
buttonEquals["command"] = ops.calc_total

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `functions` class, you have both a method and an instance variable named `operation`. When your callback tries to call the method via `ops.operation`, it gets the instance variable instead, which, after `__init__` has run, will be `False`. Instance variables "shadow" class variables (such as methods).

To fix this, change the name of either the method or the variable. Then you can refer to each one unambiguously.